# Creating a grid of boxes

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm attempting to create a 2x1x2 grid of boxes using BoxGeometry. However, I don't want a mesh for each box, I want one single mesh.

So, I have a class (Block) which has a method to create the box geometry and return the `position` and `index` of each one. I create a new Block inside a loop, storing the `position` and `index` of each one in a parent array.

Once I have all of the information, I create a mesh from the positional data of each block.

However, all of the blocks appear on top of each other and I am not sure how to adjust their position based on the position of the block (Vector3).

Here is the loop to create each block and get its positional data, adding to the parent array

```js
const positions: Array<number> = []
const indices: Array<number> = []

this.blocks.forEach((row, rowIndex) => {
  row.forEach((block, blockIndex) => {
    const data = block.getGeometryData()
    positions.push(...data.positions)
    indices.push(...data.indices)
  })
})

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(positions, 3))
geometry.setIndex(indices)

this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, this.material)
this.object.add(this.mesh)
```

And here is the `getGeometryData` for the block

```js
public getGeometryData (): any {
  const boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry()

  return {
    positions: boxGeo.getAttribute('position').array,
    indices: boxGeo.index?.array,
  }
}
```

I can confirm they overlap because each block has a transparency, and this changes in the render as I increase the block count.

Here's a single block

[image]

And here's 4 (2x1x2)

[image]

Changing the position data of the box geometry does nothing but make each block bigger. Here, I am adding 10 to each position point

```js
public getGeometryData (): any {
  const boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry()
  const positions = boxGeo.getAttribute('position').toJSON() || { array: [] }
  const newPositions: Array<number> = []

  positions.array.forEach((p, i) => {
    newPositions[i] = p + 10
  })

  boxGeo.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(newPositions, 3))

  return {
    positions: boxGeo.getAttribute('position').array,
    indices: boxGeo.index?.array,
  }
}
```

And notice how much bigger the cube is (use the sphere for reference)

[image]

Is there a way to change the position of this geometry based on the Vector3 coordinates passed?

The following is a reproducible example:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene()
scene.background = new THREE.Color('lightblue')

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true })
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
renderer.setAnimationLoop(() => {
  animate()
})

camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 100)
camera.position.set(2, 0, 2)
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0)

document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

const animate = () => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
}

const positions = []
const indices = []

for (let k = 0; k < 1; k++) {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {    
      const boxGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry()
      positions.push(...boxGeo.getAttribute('position').array)
      indices.push(...boxGeo.index?.array)
    }
  }
}

const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry()
geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(positions, 3))
geometry.setIndex(indices)

const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 'green' })
material.transparent = true
material.opacity = 0.1

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
scene.add(mesh)

const sphereGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(.2)
const sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeo)
scene.add(sphereMesh)
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add a [mre].

Comment: Why not use `BufferGeometryUtils.mergeGeometries()` or instancing?

Comment: Instancing was an option at first, but I want to hide certain faces that are facing other boxes, and with instancing, each geometry has to be the same. Merging sounds like a good idea though...